# How do I insert a string into a linked list in c language?

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to insert a string userId if it doesn't already exist in the linked list. This is my code:

```
Node *insertLL(Node **ppHead, User user){

    Node *pPrecedes;
    Node *pNew;
    Node *pNext;
    Node *pFind;
    int pHead;
    Fillup fillup; //file with user information

    //searches for the user
    pFind= searchLL(*ppHead, fillup.szUserId, &pPrecedes);

    if(pFind == NULL)   
    {
        return allocateNode(user);      

        if (strcmp(pPrecedes->user.szUserId, pFind)!= 0) //pFind seems wrong
            pNew->pNext = pPrecedes->pNext;
        else
            pNew->pNext = pPrecedes->pNext;
            pPrecedes->pNext = pNew;

    }
    return pNew;
}
```

Comment: Not much point in having code after the return statement.  It won't be executed.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], then read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. And then [edit] your question, as it stands here it is imposisble to answer. All we can say now is: "there might be a bug somewhere in your code".

Answer (score 0):

things wrong with the posted code that are certainly not helping

```
if(pFind == NULL)   
{
    return allocateNode(user);      <<< == nothing will be executed after this line

    if (strcmp(pPrecedes->user.szUserId, pFind)!= 0) //pFind seems wrong
        pNew->pNext = pPrecedes->pNext;
    else   
        pNew->pNext = pPrecedes->pNext;
        pPrecedes->pNext = pNew;  <<<<< == should this line be dependant on the else above. The indentation says yes but there are no braces

}
```

and yes I know, I will get down voted cos this is 'not an answer' - whatever, I will take the hit just to see if I can help out

Comment: I am just glad that you took the time to reply!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the correct code for this!!!I should have mentioned this but I had another function searchLL that already compared and searched for the user so strcmp was unnecessary. I had to make 2 new if-statements. One where if the string already exists it just returns that string. The other in case the string has to be inserted at the beginning where it doesn't have a preceding string. I also had to open up some space for my new string.
Node *insertLL(Node **ppHead, User user)
{

```
Node *pPrecedes;
Node *pNew;
Node *pNext;
Node *pFind;    

//searches the user //searchLL is a differen't function
pFind= searchLL(*ppHead, user.szUserId, &pPrecedes);

if (pFind!= NULL) //if pFind already exists
    return pFind;   

    pNew=allocateNode(user);//get space for pNew

if(pFind == NULL) //if pFind doesn't exist insert pFind
{
    //insert at the beginning
    if(pPrecedes == NULL) //if there is no pPrecedes
    {
        pNew->pNext = *ppHead; //pNew's next will be the head
        *ppHead = pNew; //pNew is now the new head
    }
    //insert in the middle
    else
    {
        pNew->pNext = pPrecedes->pNext; 
        pPrecedes->pNext = pNew;
    }
}
return pNew;
```

}